# Doubt in Fraction and percentage

Tags: fractions

There's a question in a book,

```
16 2/3% of 600 gm - 33 1/3% of 180 gm
```

I was solving it like regular method which i use to find x% of a number, for eg.

```
20% of 200 =1/5*200=40.
```

But, when I convert mixed fraction *(16 2/3%)* into improper fraction *(50/3)*, and then multiply it by *600* the result I get is wrong.

The book has a different formula of solving it:

```
[(50/3) * (1/100) * (600)] - [(100/3) * (1/3) * (180)]
```

I cant understand why should I add *(1/100)* in between the *(50/30)* and *600*.

And why is there *(1/3)* in between *(100/3)* and *180*.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $x$% of 600 gm is $\frac{x}{100}\times 600$gm. Now substitute $x=50/3$. Do the same thing for the next term.

Answer (score 1):

$16 \frac{2}{3}\% \text{ of } 600 \text{gm} - 33 \frac{1}{3}\% \text{ of } 180 \text {gm}$

$\frac{50}{3}\% \text{ of } 600 \text{gm} - \frac{100}{3}\% \text{ of } 180 \text {gm}$

$\frac{50}{3}\% \times 600 \text{gm} - \frac{100}{3}\% \times 180 \text {gm}$

$\frac{50}{3} \times \frac{600}{\textbf{100}} \text{gm} - \frac{100}{3} \times \frac{180}{\textbf{100}} \text {gm}$

$\frac{50}{3} \times 6 \text{gm} -  \frac{180}{3} \text {gm}$

$100 \text{gm} -  60 \text {gm} =\boxed{40\text{gm}}$.

To answer your query: whenever you remove the $\%$ you have to divide by $\textbf{100}$.

Comment: I noticed that 1/5 can be directly multiplied by the number to get the percentage of a number, but when there is an improper fraction (50/3 in our case) we have to first divide (50/3) by 100 and then multiply with the number, am I correct?

Comment: No Rishabh, you cannotjust multiply any number by $1/5$ to get the percentage. Consider this -- In a test of 40 marks you got 20. What is % of marks: According to your technique multiplying $20\times\frac{1}{5}=4\%$ which is wrong. 
Percentage would be $\frac{20}{40}\times 100 = 50\%$

Comment: Thank you @Vineet Kumar, got it!